# Restricting a user to one folder and SSH access to MySQL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, permissions, putty

I want to have user with access to only one folder.

I followed [unix.stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208960/how-to-restrict-a-user-to-one-folder-and-not-allow-them-to-move-out-his-folder), **badr** answer, I am able to create a user with access to only one folder. It is working fine. The user is able to create / transfer files. I am able to connect with WinSCP.

added below content at the bottom of **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
Match Group exchangefiles
  # Force the connection to use SFTP and chroot to the required directory.
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  ChrootDirectory /var/www/GroupFolder/
  # Disable tunneling, authentication agent, TCP and X11 forwarding.
  PermitTunnel no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

**When I try to login with Putty, Putty console is automatically closed.**

I want to give below permission to user,

```
Need to login with Putty (SSH access - Should not have permission to go out from his directory)
Can able to run Python script / Java files
Can able to access MySql
```

Any idea on how to proceed on this ?

Comment: ForceCommand prevents using anything except `sftp`

Comment: Did you consider `sudo` without administrative privileges for what you need?

Comment: @Hastur Could you please elaborate it ?

Comment: @Jakuje How to accomplish my scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your wishlist, you probably want to build a jail yourself, rather than using the built-in features of your SSH-server. For example, have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-restricting-ssh-user-session-to-a-directory-chrooted-jail/), so that you have the flexibility of chrooting to a very minimal jail (confined in one folder like you already have), but with the ability to add the executables you want to give this user privileges to, for instance python.